# Wrapping a computational library to implement another one

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I intend to take another step in my machine learning endeavour this summer, I'd like to understand the Metal API and how to write kernels for computation.

However, the first step (barring the 'hello worlds' of the metal api) is to wrap Numpy into an API which I can implement in metal.

Does this idea make sense?

src/math/matlib.py

```
import platform
_impl = None


o_system = platform.platform()
if o_system == 'Darwin':
    import impls.metal_math as metal
    _impl = metal
elif o_system == 'Linux':
    import numpy as np
    _impl = np
elif o_system == 'Windows':
    import numpy as np
    _impl = np
else:
    import numpy as np
    _impl = np


def array(x):
    """docs to be written"""
    return _impl.array(x)


def square(x, y):
    """docs to be written"""
    return _impl.square(x, y)


def T(x):
    """docs to be written"""
    return array(x).T


def dot(x, y):
    """docs to be written"""
    return _impl.dot(x, y)


def add(x, y):
    """docs to be written"""
    return _impl.add(x, y)
```

src/math/impls/metal.py (not yet written, to be understood and learned)

```
def array(x):
    return 'MY NATIVE METAL ARRAY WRAPPER'

... all other functions.
```

Comment: Python has [first class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) so unless you need some wrapper code between the implementations, you can just do `array = _impl.array` instead of copying the arguments twice (if you need to edit its documentation you can do `array.__doc__ = """your docs here"""` on the next line). Also it seems like you don't need those `elif`s because the `else` handles them the same. Otherwise sure, why not?

Comment: While you're working on this, you could make your life easier by just automatically importing and re-exporting everything, so just do `if o_system == 'Darwin': from impls.metal_math import *` and `else: from numpy import *` but in the finished product it's probably a better idea to carefully choose what you're re-exporting like you've done, but again if the function signatures are all the same you can just do `if o_system == 'Darwin': from impls.metal_math import array, square, T` and they will be re-exported by your module, you don't *need* to define a function with the same name.

Comment: One reason to not do that and do it like you've done it is to let someone using your code change the `_impl` after importing your code, so they could do `import matlib` and then `matlib._impl = their_own_impl` and then `matlib.array()` would use their implementation of `array`. I guess I'm not sure what exactly it is you're asking.